# Obstruction for nonzero section of nonorientable vector bundle

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Suppose we have real $n$-vector bundle $p:E\to X$ over some $CW$-complex $X$. It is well-known that if $E$ is *orientable* (i.e. $\pi_1X$ acts on orientation of fibers trivially) then the obstruction to construct a nonzero section of $E$ is [Euler class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class) $e\in H^n(X,\mathbb Z)$.

In case $E$ is *nonorientable* one can define the *orientation sheaf* 
$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\widetilde{\mathbb Z}}$ $\ZZ$ (which fiber over a point $x$ is $H^{n-1}(p^{-1}(x)\setminus0,\mathbb Z)$), and then define the obstruction to construct a nonzero section of $E$ as certain element $\newcommand{\ee}{\widetilde{e}}$ $\ee\in H^n(X,\ZZ)$.

I have difficulties with computing $\ee$ in particular cases and with some properties of $\ee$. E.g. how to understend that $\ee(TM)=\chi(M)$ (with right orientation -- how to chose this orientation?). Is there any litrature describing this characteristic class and how to work with?

Answer (score 1):

I studied local coefficients and put an explonation in [the article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2020.107168), see $\S$2.2-2.3. Here is the answer for the questions (Proposition 3):

A local orientation of the manifold and a local orientation of the fibers of its tangent bundle naturally determine one another.
In other words, for $E=TM$ we have a *canonical* isomorphism $\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}_M\otimes\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}_E\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.
Here $\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}_E$ and $\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}_M$ are the orientation sheafs.

So the index of a zero of any section of $TM$ is a well defined integer and does not depend of the (local) orientation.

Therefore we can
use the same strategy as in orientable case, e.g. in [Prasolov, *Elements of Combinatorial and Differential Topology*, chapt. 5, $\S$4.2].
Triangulate $M$ and consider a vector field which has a single zero of index $(-1)^k$ at the center of every $k$-simplex.
Then the sum of the indices of the zeroes of this vector field equals $\chi(M)$.

Note that the total index is an invariant of the vector bundle $TM$,
since it is a Poincaré dual of an obstruction class, which lays in $H^n(M;\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}_E)$
So for any other vector field with isolated zeroes the total index still equals $\chi(M)$.